Is this use of 'whom' grammatical?
I read the following sentence on a Wikipedia page that sounded odd:

Carlson traveled to Russia in February 2024 to interview President Vladimir Putin, whom he "has been an outspoken defender of".

I understand that 'whom' is an objective pronoun, meaning it can represent an object. 'President Vladimir Putin' is the object. Consider that the subject (Carlson) respects the object (President Vladimir Putin). The sentence would then become:

Carlson traveled to Russia in February 2024 to interview President Vladimir Putin, whom he respects.

That makes sense. But the original sentence above sounds odd though I cannot clearly articulate why. I also feel that the sentence needlessly uses double quotes hampering its readability, although I understand that readability can be subjective.
That Wikipedia page is protected. I, a small-scale Wikipedia editor, submitted a less convoluted (in my opinion) replacement request but it was rejected stating that the original statement was grammatical (without further clarification). Can someone elucidate?
Note: I am only interested in the grammatical correctness of that sentence. No political strings are attached to my question.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

In a comment BillJ wrote:

Accusative "whom" is fine (if rather formal) in both cases -- object of the prep "of" and object of the verb "respects". There is no sensible rule that says you can't end a clause with a preposition -- it happens all the time.



Carlson traveled to Russia in February 2024 to interview President Vladimir Putin, of whom he "has been an outspoken defender".

This would probably be the preferred version as the "of" creates the objective case in its object and should be close to it.
The "rule" (if it exists) of not ending a sentence with a preposition is often ironically cited as
"A preposition is a bad thing to end a sentence with."
Or the hypercorrected
"Ending a sentence with a preposition is something up with which I will not put."

Yes, both sentences are grammatically correct. But the outspoken one is not properly edited for a spoken register.
They could have just as well written:
Carlson traveled to Russia in February 2024 to interview President Vladimir Putin, of whom he has been an outspoken defender.
OR
who he defends in an outspoken manner.
to be an outspoken defender of someone is not 100% synonymous per se to respect someone.
In formal written texts (like newspaper articles or magazine articles) you would not find the of at the end, despite it being grammatical. That's the real point here.
The outspoken defender phrase is taken from the BBC's report on this which you can access through the OP's link.See the footnote at 213. The BBC article states: Tucker Carlson has been an outspoken defender of Mr Putin since the war began.
Another similar example:
The politician to whom they were referring was Putin.
Putin was the politician they were referring to.
